# ClassSecurityInfo.declarePrivate() etc. as Python decorators

Tags: plone, zope

Does declarePrivate() et. al. Zope 2 style access control declarations have any modern Python syntax method decorator?

E.g.

```
class EncryptedField(StringField):
    """
    """
    security = ClassSecurityInfo()

    # Something more nice here? like @private?
    security.declarePrivate('get')

    def get(self, instance, **kwargs):
        value = ObjectField.get(self, instance, **kwargs)
        if getattr(self, 'raw', False):
            return value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, we are still stuck with this syntax.

They cannot be converted to decorators so easily because they are a class-level declaration, not actually attached to the methods. You'd need to play nasty tricks with the calling frame to get back to the class declaration and the `security` object to make this work.

Thus, there is a step where the `security` object is processed to turn the declarations into class attributes that Zope2 recognizes; this step is these days automatically taken care of by the archetypes `registerType` call.